# Configuring Elasticsearch for Java Integration Tests

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I inherited a project that has a lot of sleep statements to allow Elasticsearch to index in its integration tests... deep sigh.

Most of the time I've got a tiny amount of data in Elasticsearch and I'd really like to have 0 wait. I set up a node in the JVM for my tests as follows:

```
ImmutableSettings.Builder elasticsearchSettings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
        .put("http.enabled", "false")
        .put("path.data", dataDirectory)
        .put("script.disable_dynamic", "false")
        .put("script.inline", "on")
        .put("script.indexed", "on")
        .put(EsExecutors.PROCESSORS, 1)
        .put("index.store.type", "ram")
        .put("gateway.type", "none")
        ;

node = nodeBuilder()
        .clusterName("cluster_" + (new java.util.Random().nextInt()))
        .local(true)
        .data(true)
        .settings(elasticsearchSettings.build())
        .node();

Client client = node.client();

Settings indexSettings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
        .put("number_of_shards", 1)
        .put("number_of_replicas", 1)
        .build();
CreateIndexRequest indexRequest = new CreateIndexRequest(
        "test_inst", indexSettings);

client.admin().indices().create(indexRequest).actionGet();
```

However I'm still getting a lot of failures when I decrease the sleep time, and some queries that pass against an external elastic search instance fail against the node run in the JVM.

I tried forcing a refresh using:

```
elasticSearchClientUtil.getClient().admin().indices().prepareRefresh().execute().actionGet();
```

but that doesn't seem to help with the problem. Some of the failures are intermittent which implies to me that I'm being affected the 1 second refresh interval.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to force indexing so that I can speed these tests up?

Comment: What tests are failing when you remove/decrease sleep? executing a refresh on your index should make docs immediately searchable.

Comment: The tests involve calls to a web application that does a search against the elasticsearch instance and returns the results as json. The forced refresh occurs before the request is made in the tests.

Comment: Refresh after each set of index operations, or you can [force index operations to trigger a refresh](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-refresh). Warnings about doing this at the link (should be fine for tests)

Comment: That's an interesting idea, although it looks like you need to do this on every statement that inserts/updates the document? That's less than ideal.

Comment: It might be a bit late, but `CLIENT.admin().indices().refresh(new RefreshRequest(INDEX)).actionGet();` this has done the job for me in my integ tests